# Rails server working locally not on other machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 4.2.4 version for creating a web application.
The application is working locally 
ex:- http://localhost:3000
But when i try to open it on another machine in same network 
ex:- http://My-IP:3000
It does not open the application.
I am able to ping my machine from another machine.
Please let me know if i have to modify any configurations in the Rails file system.

Comment: use the `-b 0.0.0.0` option when running the server

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot open it using other machine easily as running localhost:3000 like you do in local machine.

Unless you will configure your network, like using IP address or static IP which uses and open the port 3000.

Or you can try like **rails s -b 0.0.0.0** for opening the port.
I think you can access it via your IP like 192.168.x.x:3000

Add this to your config/boot.rb

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge(Host:  '0.0.0.0', Port: 3000)
    end
  end
end
```

Then, simply run: **rails s**

Use you IP to access it in other computer with the same network like:
192.18.x.x:3000

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but unfortunately its not working for me

Comment: Please check the other suggestion, in my answer. If it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, same out come not working. But if i try to do the same exercise with Apache Tomcat it works.

Answer (score 0):

first open your terminal write the command

```
ifconfig
```

and find your ip address like `inet addr:192.168.1.4`

Now go to your rails application terminal and write

```
rails s -b 'your ip address'
```

Example: `rails s -b 192.168.1.4`